# Issue with my links or permalinks

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have a wordpress site that is set to www.mydomainsample.com, however when it opens other link for instance the service page, it will show localhost/wordpress/index.php/services.

Any idea how I can change to www.mydomainsample.com/services when I open the service page. Thanks and have great day :)

Comment: That means you have hard-coded urls or if you migrate from localhost to production you haven't chagne the `siteurl` and `home` WordPress options. Also a modified htacess could be possible. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

1) add or edit the .htaccess file, it should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2) Go to admin panel -> settings -> Permalink and select Post name, if this does not fix, then click on Custom Structure and write `/%postname%/`